# What does Islam say about X?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Questions of the form "What does Islam say about X?" ([e.g.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23228/2469)) are simply not constructive and should be closed.  Unfortunately, many such questions (including the one linked) are not closed and are even upvoted and answered. This practice simply encourages the asking of bad questions.

Such questions are not at all specific enough to be answerable. For example, using the question linked here, I could cite basically any Islamic teaching and have my answer be true. "Islam says that introverts should not eat pork" is a correct answer to that question. Of course, its a useless answer, but if a useless answer correctly answers a question, its because the question is really useless itself.

Comment: What if the person is considered and worried about that X, only then he/she asks about that as question. We can close, but only after answering... We cannot take the risk of hurting them. ryt? :)

Comment: @servantofWiser No. If the person is concerned about X, he would take the time to formulate a proper question. I'm not saying that we shouldn't answer because I'm mean and I want people who ask questions I don't like to suffer. I'm saying we shouldn't answer because the question itself is unanswerable. "What does Islam say about bananas?" is a useless question. Instead, ask, "are bananas permissible to be eaten according to Islam?" If you ask the first question, I could answer, "Islam says that bananas are yellow."

Comment: @servantofWiser [Here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23310/quranic-view-about-heritage-preservation) is another example of what I'm talking about. Thankfully, so far, this question has been downvoted. The problem with the question is that the OP doesn't specify what specifically he is interested in w.r.t. heritage preservation. It's an ambiguous question and should be closed.

Comment: Ok! so you can encourage him/her to ask better, refine the question , help him help us better... ! :)

Comment: I completely dis-agree with daniel. People come here to learn about islam. so all the ways should be open to them. whatever they refer in question, the experts in this community should be able to provide specific reference from Quran and hadith about it. if they dont,then its large userbase will not like it, and users may be repelled.

Comment: @hamzaislam I'm not saying that certain topics should be off-limits. I'm just saying if you want to ask a question, it needs to be an answerable question. "What does Islam say about XYZ?" is usually not an answerable question.

Comment: Like i ask , what does slam says about Riba/Usury.i believe it is a genuine question. because someone (specially non-muslim) heard about it,and want to know what does islam says about this point of ususry/riba. what do you think.

Comment: @hamzaislam that question is too broad to be useful.

Comment: people will answer him about this point by references from Quran and hadith.so he will know about it that what islam says. so obviously he would have benefit,that he know it. or not?

Comment: @HamzaIslam We also expect OP to show some research effort in their questions. "what does slam says about Riba/Usury" is not the type of question we cater here unless it shows signs of research and is really specific.

Answer (score 3):

> What Islam says about Islam?

Huh! No, no. Like you said these questions are (completely) useless and show no sign of research.

Now that I think about it. It seems when OP writes "says" they could mean

> What is the Islamic ruling for introverts/X?

But again it's not any different from when we had "says" it isn't specific and answers like, what you mentioned, e.g. "By the rules of Islam introverts shouldn't eat pork", would apply.

So, what do we do about these questions?

Well, if you see that the body of the question contains a *specific question* and it's just the title that need specificity then edit it. If otherwise, then close the question as **unclear what you're asking** and vote *appropriately*!

Why "unclear what you're asking" and not "too broad". Well, not that "too broad" wouldn't apply but because unclear.. seems more appropriate here.